# sql query to return results which match a search key but also retrieves records which are alphabetically after the search key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring, patindex

The title is a mouthful but I found it hard to explain.

I had a previous web service which allowed a user to enter a search key e.g. 4, and that would return records which started with that search key 
e.g. 4, 4a, 4b.

Now I've been asked to implement a solution whereby if a user types 4, it would return results:

```
4
4a
4aa
4b
5
5a
5b
5c
5Z
6
52.
etc..
```

**for 50 records.**

I'm not sure where to start in altering the query...the col being searched is alphanumeric and that is the confusing bit.

The query itself is over 20 lines long but the part linking the results to the search key is just;

```
(col LIKE @searchKey + '[a-zA-Z.]%' OR col = @searchKey OR col >= @searchKey)
```

And as requested the ordering is:

```
ORDER BY   
        CASE WHEN col LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%' Then 1 ELSE 0 END,

                 CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 0, 

                  CASE WHEN patindex('%[a-zA-Z.]%', col) = 0

                  THEN len(col)+1

                  ELSE patindex('%[a-zA-Z.]%', col)

                  END) 

                 as INT),

    CASE WHEN col LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%' THEN SUBSTRING(col, 1,1) END,

    CASE WHEN col LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%' AND len(col) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,

    CASE WHEN col LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%' AND len(col) = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,

    CASE WHEN col LIKE '[a-zA-Z]%' AND len(col) = 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,

    col;
```

Right now if I pass in 82 for example, I am getting results:

```
8
8A
8B
8E
8H
9
9A
9C
9D
9E
82
82A
82B
82C
.
.
.
.
99R
```

However what I need is that if the user types 82, they do not receive results like 8, 8x, 9, 9x etc.

Comment: So the field is obviously a string field. Does it ever go to 2 digits? If so, you'll need to parse out the number from the character.

Comment: @Rabbit it could go to two digits yes. I'm not sure how to parse out the number of an indefinite string length

Comment: You'll need to use the PATINDEX function along with SUBSTRING to separate the field into the 2 pieces that you need. What about the alpha portion of the string? Does that ever go to 2 characters?

Comment: @Rabbit Hi yes the alpha part of the string can indeed be numeric and there is even some cases where there is a . as the first character. I will have test data tomorrow to work with and will report back then.

Comment: The test data needs to be representative of what you have. We also need to know what ordering you expect from said test data. String comparisons are not the same as numbers even if the string looks like a number.

Comment: @Rabbit see updated question

Comment: How are col and A_LOTNO related - or is next a typo: `col = @searchKey OR A_LOTNO >= @searchKey`?

Comment: You said it could start with a dot. I don't see that in the sample data, where do those go in the sort? Also, you never answered my question about whether the alpha portion of the string ever goes above 1 character.

Comment: Can the user input include the alpha portion as well? Or do they only type in the numeric part?

Comment: @Rabbit the user can input the alpha portion also yes. The alpha portion can be more than 1 character yes.

Comment: And where does the data with dots and longer alpha strings go in your sample data? We can't help you if your sample data isn't representative.

Comment: @Rabbit Sorry, I added two records to the question  (example is 4aa and 52.)

Comment: And is that everything? There's no other special characters or lower case letters?

Comment: @Rabbit No other special characters. Letters could be lower yes

Comment: And where do lower case letters fall in relation with upper case letters in the sort above?

Comment: @Rabbit The upper case would come first. That would make the most sense to me

Comment: So 8Z comes before 8a and 9aZ comes before 9aaa? Please add examples to the sample data.

Comment: @Rabbit I have since found out there is only one letter after the number part. Ordered alphabetically so 8z would come after 8A. In nearly all cases, the letters are upper but there are a few cases of lower

Comment: But your previous comment was that upper case letters come first. Please add examples to the sample data.

Comment: @Rabbit I have verified that the requirement is ordered alphabetically please. I added sample data

Comment: Since the alpha portion doesn't go beyond 1 character. You can use the solution I posted on Nov 25 with slight modification. Where ever the column or user input is referenced in the transformation, apply a LOWER and REPLACE to change the '.' to a '['. If you want a slightly simpler solution, that will have to wait, don't have enough time to write one up currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96615/discussion-between-user2363025-and-rabbit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate out the numeric portion from the alpha portion and then recombine them into a new number value that can be sorted and filtered on. You will need to do the same operation for the user input.

Note that this doesn't handle the period you mentioned in your post as you have not told us how it's supposed to be handled. If it's irrelevant, then use the replace function to get rid of it. Also, this does not handle situations where the alpha portion of the string is longer than one character.

I made the assumption that the user can input a character after their numeric input. If this is not the case, this can be simplified by not having to convert the user input and not having to multiply the numeric portion by a large number.

The 100000 should be larger than the largest number possible in the numeric portion of the string. Add additional zeroes to it as needed.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7d/462)

```
declare @t table (col varchar(4))
declare @userinput varchar(4)

set @userinput = '9C'

insert into @t values ('8')
insert into @t values ('8A')
insert into @t values ('8B')
insert into @t values ('8E')
insert into @t values ('8H')
insert into @t values ('9')
insert into @t values ('9A')
insert into @t values ('9C')
insert into @t values ('9D')
insert into @t values ('9E')
insert into @t values ('82')
insert into @t values ('82A')
insert into @t values ('82B')
insert into @t values ('82C')
insert into @t values ('99R')

;with cte as (
    select 
        col,
        CONVERT(int,
            case when PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', col) = 0 
                then col
                else LEFT(col, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', col) - 1)
            end
        ) * 100000
        +
        ascii(case when PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', col) = 0
            then ' '
            else SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', col), len(col))
        end) newcol

    from @t
)

select *
from cte
where 
    newcol >= (
        CONVERT(int,
            case when PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', @userinput) = 0 
                then @userinput
                else LEFT(@userinput, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', @userinput) - 1)
            end
        ) * 100000
        +
        ascii(case when PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', @userinput) = 0
            then ' '
            else SUBSTRING(@userinput, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', @userinput), len(@userinput))
        end)
    )
order by newcol
```

Comment: I have no experience with cte. I'm just using mssql. The entries with a dot should just go at the end

Comment: thanks, I got it working, no need for another solution

Comment: glad you got it working, just let me know if you would like me to post the simpler solution at some point and i'll write it up

Answer (score 1):

If you want alphabetically after the search key, then use `>=`:

```
where col >= @searchKey
```

Comment: really? does the >= operator work for alphanumeric strings?

Comment: It does, but with strings, '2' > '10' because it compares character by character.

Comment: @Rabbit . . . There is no "but" there.  `'2' > '10'` is different from `2 > 10`.  The first compares strings and is true.  The second compares numbers and is false.

Comment: I understand the difference between how the operator works with strings and with numbers. My comment was to point out that the solution won't work because the numeric portion of the string goes to 2+ digits.

Comment: @Rabbit . . . I see nothing in the question to suggest that the ordering is *not* alphabetic.  I can also see a reasonable interpretation that the initial digits should be treated as a number.  The OP should clarify.